# How to replace the dataset with one value if it satisfies a condition, if not with another value

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset with 30 columns. An example would look something like this

```r
data <- data.frame(name=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "C", "A", "B"),
                 place=c("B", "c", "F", "C", "G", "A", "H", "A"))
```

Now I would like to replace the whole of dataset with value of 1 if name=A and with 0 if not equal to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the row of the dataset where `name == 'A'`, you can do the follwoing,

```r
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(name=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "C", "A", "B"),
                   place=c("B", "c", "F", "C", "G", "A", "H", "A"))

data %>% 
  mutate(
    across(.fns = ~ if_else(name == "A", 1, 0))
  )

#>   name place
#> 1    1     1
#> 2    0     0
#> 3    0     0
#> 4    0     0
#> 5    0     0
#> 6    0     0
#> 7    1     1
#> 8    0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Or, if you want to replace all value of the data for `'A'` with 1 or else 0 for other value,

```r
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
    name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "C", "A", "B"),
    place = c("B", "c", "F", "C", "G", "A", "H", "A")
)

data %>%
    mutate(
        across(.fns = ~ if_else(.x == "A", 1, 0))
    )

#>   name place
#> 1    1     0
#> 2    0     0
#> 3    0     0
#> 4    0     0
#> 5    0     0
#> 6    0     1
#> 7    1     0
#> 8    0     1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>